# serving a file to loader.io in NGINX is not working

Tags: nginx

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        root /home/ec2-user;
   #     location / {
   #       proxy_pass http://sdc_servers;
   #    }
        location /loaderio-73cc9f7580b0a0844a502ff1c98e9305.txt {
           proxy_pass http://3.15.28.77/loaderio-73cc9f7580b0a0844a502ff1c98e9305/;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong trying to serve this file, I am totally lost

Answer (score 0):

> `location /loaderio-73cc9f7580b0a0844a502ff1c98e9305.txt { proxy_pass http://3.15.28.77/loaderio-73cc9f7580b0a0844a502ff1c98e9305/; }`
>
> Instead of passing the token in the proxy_pass, try something like
>
> `location /loaderio-9f8a9889007f8a2721b6245b80344b75.txt { root /<location_to_the_file>/loader/; try_files /loader.txt =404; }`
>
> loader - directory containing loader.txt which contains the actual
> token provided by loader.io.